# c++ networking and locking issue

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, locking

my c++ application manage several sockets and their send + receive. in order to ignore issues I'm doing lock by a semaphore before the send an receive on a socket.
when I run the application on 100 machines I see that sometimes can be a period of time that my machine don't send ack for messages it gets (I see in wireshark the packet and the retransmissions on this packet). also in this period of time I see that my application don't send anything from what it has to send.

my question is: can this issue be from te root cause of the locking mechanism? does the locking mechanism - when I lock a socket cause the OS also to not send anything on this socket? and maybe you'll know also: how to ignore this behavior?

thanks

Comment: After a long consideration, I marked this as "not a question". Due to the lack of information, this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Is the semaphore per-connection? Or one big semaphore for the whole application? Did you set the sockets non-blocking? How do you decide when to try to receive from a socket? And why not just use Boost?

Comment: semaphore per connection. socket are non-blocking

Answer (score 1):

Oh, this doesn't sound good.  You should provide more details of your app design, esp. some code around the locking.

Locking a resource is typically done with a mutex, but a semaphore initialized to 1 will do, at a push.

Most important: are you handling all exceptions thrown by network calls inside the lock?